# How to plot longitude/latitude as points to plot borders of a country

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have long lists of longitude and latitude coordinates, i'm trying to plot them using matplotlib to get the borders of a country, but somehow i'm getting a very weird graph with no points at all and weird axis, the code

```
        map_long , map_lat = self.split_longlat_columns()
        plt.plot(map_long, map_lat , "k.", markersize = 0.1 , markeredgecolor='none')
        plt.xlabel("Longitude")
        plt.xticks(fontsize = 'xx-small')
        plt.ylabel("Latitude")
        plt.show()
```

the lists (shortened):

```
map_lat=
['58.6439983232014\n',
 '58.64938696931103\n',
 '58.66327511045544\n',
 '58.684424613275304\n',
 '58.68736369535053\n',
 '58.68755586640848\n',
 '58.69184665625426\n',
 '58.694754802869554\n',
 '58.70314664855054\n',
 '58.71280281775024\n',
 '58.7169210095724\n',
 '58.723549551070356\n',
 '58.720046306744436\n',
 '58.72178486911972\n',
 '58.72563399376825\n',
 '58.735061095701184\n',
 '58.74040486399477\n',
 '58.77372011937943\n',
 '58.78329824492\n',
 '58.78431662379136\n',
 '58.788349571569114\n',
 '58.81067682432557\n',
 '58.83411598647745\n',
 '58.83677958604884\n',
 '58.83511482616359\n',
 '58.84478376337858\n',
 '58.88086739186455\n',
 '58.90037765103952\n',
 '58.998367707689965\n',
 '59.053036704007695\n',
 '59.076761018380914\n',
 '59.08914402110779\n',
 '59.09182661091842\n',
 '59.10152471475993\n',
 '59.14490670122853\n',
 '59.14042182511641\n',
 '59.10509789930403\n',
 '59.085387123085525\n',
 '59.08246708287086\n',
 '59.084818561276485\n',
 '59.079046798848516\n',
 '59.063633542699066\n',
 '58.95148680168038\n',
 '58.93177429491041\n',
 '58.894958892963295\n',
 '58.88650172892071\n',
 '58.85103961017208\n',
 '58.81280729297566\n',
 '58.79301578872083\n',
 '58.79420081893428\n',
 '58.82180306174451\n',
 '58.83262196140653\n',
 '58.88684631383201\n',
 '58.90339649378325\n',
 '58.94825015646971\n',
 '58.970403854377885\n',
 '58.98409452447718\n',
 '59.015869753586344\n',
 '59.04057607564951\n',
 '59.058085103337746\n',
 '59.06735425234107\n',
 '59.07512640546823\n',
 '59.073327886161366\n',
 '59.06892038253984\n',
 '59.061663180351786\n',
 '59.06250179195174\n',
 '59.07262318596669\n',
 '59.08977597149177\n',
 '59.095380934682545\n',
 '59.10254561952161\n',]
```

```
map_long=
['17.11565548982419',
 '17.137389780738154',
 '17.151377672957427',
 '17.141415270927155',
 '17.128059514473474',
 '17.109200964514258',
 '17.10128096486101',
 '17.090608676414938',
 '17.09360896891125',
 '17.11014401877681',
 '17.118392634434365',
 '17.15640420124105',
 '17.220997683422897',
 '17.31546681440188',
 '17.34531090742604',
 '17.37810696347918',
 '17.39993796180106',
 '17.42847718358896',
 '17.447834293947768',
 '17.47761077198037',
 '17.491312893990763',
 '17.500512910295093',
 '17.53141979072123',
 '17.54237748642013',
 '17.56124196396938',
 '17.572558943040505',
 '17.601496462686104',
 '17.61063792964995',
 '17.62663946796767',
 '17.629531197596197',
 '17.638969624314637',
 '17.655987713427386',
 '17.664307220031034',
 '17.67301808902235',
 '17.68084147235308',
 '17.699704438497267',
 '17.71685330589693',
 '17.721209168237372',
 '17.729219436756733',
 '17.75934123104118',]
```

and thats what im getting when trying to plot them
[image]

What could be the problem and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type of your lat/lon lists is incorrect, you need to convert all those string values to float.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues:

1. length of lat and lon lists shoud be equal. Now it is 42:70
2. if you want to have markeredgecolor set to none you have to incerease markersize

**from this**

```
plt.plot(map_long, map_lat , "k.", markersize = 0.1 , markeredgecolor='none')
```

**to something like this**

```
plt.plot(map_long, map_lat , "k.", markersize = 3 , markeredgecolor='none')
```

[image]
Then it looks like this

Comment: Actually both lists have the size 7350 , so they are equal, and when I increase markersize i only get some points at the middle!